# NSAssert not called in debug mode

Tags: ios, nsassert

I received a big iOS project, in this project every `NSAssert()` are skipped **even in debug!**

I added a test to check is `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` is defined even in debug mode and no, it isn't defined.

```
#ifdef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTION
    NSLog(@"Assertion are blocked");
#endif
```

Old C-style `assert()` are called as usual.

This code:

```
NSLog(@"AA");
NSAssert(FALSE,@"TRY ASSERT");
NSLog(@"BB");
```

produce this preprocessed code

```
    if (!(0)) {
    [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInMethod:_cmd
                                                        object:self
                                                          file:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"/Users/..../AppDelegate.m"]
                                                    lineNumber:106
                                                   description:(@"TRY ASSERT")];
}
```

and i correct my post, NSAssert aren't skipped, but the app simply hangs, even if the NSAssert are TRUE :(

Comment: Open one of your compilation units that has the `NSAssert` macro in it, open the assistant editor, and choose the `Preprocess` view. Take a look at what those lines are getting pre-processed into.

Comment: Did you install your own root-level assertion handler? If not, is it possible you added a library that installed one that's misbehaving? Try breaking on exceptions and stepping up into whatever the root level handler is, if you're unsure. If it's hanging, it sounds like your handler is misbehaving.